# use web_sys::HtmlButtonElement fails

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

Managed to build and run some of the examples in https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/tree/master/examples

Then started with little prototype program for Dom manipulation, things works, until stuck on this.

---

Use
https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.35/web_sys/struct.HtmlButtonElement.html

lists `pub struct HtmlButtonElement`, similar to

https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.35/web_sys/struct.Element.html and
https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.35/web_sys/struct.HtmlElement.html

Having:

```
use web_sys::Element;
use web_sys::HtmlElement;
use web_sys::HtmlButtonElement;
```

Gives compile error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `web_sys::HtmlButtonElement`
 --> src/lib.rs:8:5
  |
8 | use web_sys::HtmlButtonElement;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `HtmlButtonElement` in the root
```

While `Element` and `HtmlElement` are found in `web_sys`

What is the difference/missing for `HtmlButtonElement`? Does the `no HtmlButtonElement in the root` message give a clue?

Comment: > This API requires the following crate features to be activated: HtmlButtonElement - https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.HtmlButtonElement.html

Comment: Thanks have overseen that, it was missing, when adding the feature it is found.

Comment: yes this answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment by @chpio. When adding `HtmlButtonElement` to features in Cargo.toml `HtmlButtonElement` is found when building.